# How to move to specific section of external page

Tags: html

After opening a new tab on my site, I want to move the focus to the bottom of the page on the external site.  The reason for this is that the item I really want to show is at the bottom of the page (which is actually some search results).

Here's the link as it currently stands:

> `<a href="http://www.approvedworkshops.co.uk/search/map/wales/#results" target="_blank">NCC Approved</a>`

and I want to highlight 'Cymru Caravan & Trailer Services' which is the last item in the list.

All help much appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not possible to link to the bottom of an external page, nor to highlight any items on it. JavaScript workarounds  are out of the question as well, because they can't access pages from external domains.

In your case, though, you could use a kuldgy workaround and  jump to the element with the ID "footer" which is at the bottom of the page:

```
http://www.approvedworkshops.co.uk/search/map/wales/#footer
```

this is the best you will be able to do without fetching the whole page onto your server first.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look and this isn't a kludge, it is in fact [part of the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3):

> We may achieve the same effect **(as a named anchor)** by making the header elements themselves the anchors ...
>
> ```
> <H2 id="section1">Introduction</H2>
> ```

Good to know, as dropping `<a name="...">` around the place can be a hassle when styling.

Comment: it's a kludge in that it's not targeting the item he wants, but a different element on the page that happens to be at the bottom. But cheers for digging up the reference :)