# Linking to the end of another page in which i have no access to the source of

Tags: javascript, html

The website i'm trying to link to is pretty much a text document (see below), i'm trying to link to the last line preferable, highlighting it would be ideal but a link to the end of the page would work.

I've tried various code snippets, but as i have no access to the code of the page i cannot create anchor in the target page and link directly to that.

if i can get the following code to run on the page once i have navigated to it, i believe that would solve the problem, but my JS knowledge does not extend that far

```
window.onload=toBottom;

function toBottom()
{
alert("Scrolling to bottom ...");
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

i am linking using the following code

```
`<a href="(http://www.loebner.net/Prizef/TuringArticle.html)" class="author">&mdash; Alan Turing </a>`
```

http://www.loebner.net/Prizef/TuringArticle.html

Comment: This is a relevant post about your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958162/how-to-move-to-specific-section-of-external-page. However, it does not provide a solution for your page since there is nothing to work with on the external page. It's also entirely impossible to run Javascript on another page for obvious reasons.. So unless the external page is changed, there is currently no way to link to the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanest solution was contacting the site administrator of the site and setting up a mirror on my server of the original file and adding an #ID to the element i wanted to deeplink to and linking to the #ID from within my webpage

```
href="<c:url value="loebner#ID"/>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would deeplink and find an ID on the remote page and link directly to that so for example

www.loebner.net/Prizef/TuringArticle.html#ELEMENTID

However if the page does not have an element at the bottom with an ID then might be a problem, do you have access to that page to add an ID?

Comment: unless it's possible to link to a </body> or </html> element, there is no real id scheme in the page, also it is an external link which i have no access to

Comment: Im not sure if it is possible, not that i am aware anyway. Maybe have a little google an see if there are any jQuery plugins and snippets that can do this.

Comment: i've had a look and it doesn't seem possible using JQuery, no idea if it is possible, but opening the page within/above the current page and getting it to run the above script would work, but i have no idea if that is possible